# Dropwizard Integrated Testing with TestResource

Tags: java, rest, testing, dropwizard

Does anyone knows how to add a test Resource (i.e. one that is only for testing purposes and not added in run() method of the app)?

Here is an example:

```
public class MyTest {   
    @ClassRule
    public static final DropwizardAppRule<TestConfiguration> RULE =
            new DropwizardAppRule<TestConfiguration>(MyApp.class, "my-app-config.yaml");


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
    {
        MyTest.RULE.getEnvironment().jersey().register(new JustForTestingResource());
    }


    @Test
    public final void testTestResource()
    {
        Client client = new Client();

        ClientResponse response = client.resource(
            String.format("http://localhost:%d/rest/v1/test", RULE.getLocalPort()))
            .get(ClientResponse.class);

        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));   
    }
}
```

and

```
public class JustForTestingRessource {


    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getInTestResource()
    {
        return Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).entity("get @Path(\"test\") is ok").build();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the added resource is not added and I get resource not found 404 error response. It seems that I am registering the new resource after resource publishing and there is no refresh inside Dropwizard after start.

I dont want to extend my Application class and I dont want to insert test code into my real application code. Does anyone knows how to register the test resource without registering it in run() method of the Application?

This works, but a new class is needed:

```
public class TestService extends MyService{


    @Override
    public void run(
        TestConfigurationconfiguration,
        Environment environment) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {       
        environment.jersey().register(new JustForTestingRessource());
        super.run(configuration,environment);
    }

}
```

Call in JUnit as already known:

```
@ClassRule
public static DropwizardAppRule<TestConfiguration> RULE =
        new DropwizardAppRule<TestConfiguration>(TestService.class, "my-app-config.yaml");
```

Comment: Something like RULE.addRessource(...) would be nice ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Removing previous answer because it didn't solve your problem the way you wanted to do it.

I dug into the environment startup code and realized the reason why registering a controller didn't make it available is because jetty had already been started. If you stop jetty, register your controller and start jetty back up again, your resource will be available and you can use it in your test.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
{
    MyTest.RULE.environment.applicationContext.stop()
    MyTest.RULE.environment.jersey().register(new JustForTestingResource())
    MyTest.RULE.environment.applicationContext.start()
}
```

Comment: Yeah but then I have also additional Testcode in my application. To prevent that it is even better to create a class extending MyApplication and overwrite run() like i mentioned above. But I asked for an better solution adding a resource just in the TestClass, and thats why I can not agree with your solution.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why three lines of code specific to checking an environment variable is an unacceptable option?

Comment: I avoid Testcode in LiveCode, so even my class TestService extends MyService is a better solution, because I have no "just for testing purpose" methods in my application. With this overwritten run() method I can clearly separate my test- and livecode.

With your solution it would be possible to do a wrong configuration inside your live *.yml and then you have lines of code just for testing in your application.

Comment: @user3280180 please see my updated answer. I believe this should work for you and no code should be necessary outside of the test itself.

Comment: Yeah now It stops and restarts with new resource, but I added sleeping for 1000ms after starting. So the initial question was answered, even if I have now some other exceptions, but I dont know if this is my own problem or due to the restart. I mark this as resolved!

Comment: @user3280180 stopping and restarting didn't have any impact in my application because nothing is exercised aside from initialization and startup. If you need some more assistance let me know or open another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can test the Resource itself in a Jersey Container without starting a full dw-instance.

Check the ["Testing Resources" section](http://dropwizard.io/manual/testing.html).

```
import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class PersonResourceTest {

     private static final PeopleStore dao = mock(PeopleStore.class);

     @ClassRule
     public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
        .addResource(new PersonResource(dao))
        .build();

     private final Person person = new Person("blah", "blah@example.com");

     @Before
     public void setup() {
         when(dao.fetchPerson(eq("blah"))).thenReturn(person);
         // we have to reset the mock after each test because of the
         // @ClassRule, or use a @Rule as mentioned below.
         reset(dao);
     }

     @Test
     public void testGetPerson() {
         assertThat(resources.client().resource("/person/blah").get(Person.class))
            .isEqualTo(person);
         verify(dao).fetchPerson("blah");
     }
 }
```

Comment: I have created resource tests already, but I inserted a new filter and thats why I need "a full dw-instance".

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with the @ClassRule, maybe it can help to somebody..
In my test (Groovy) the invocation of RULE.getApplication() or getEnvironment() from @BeforeClass method returned null:

```
def setupSpec() {
    RULE.application.run()
}
```

shown

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method run() on null object
```

I.e. RULE.testSupport had both null application and environment.

I found out that the call to
RULE.testSupport.before()
just before run() solves the error:

```
def setupSpec() {
    RULE.testSupport.before()
    RULE.application.run()
}
```

And then @AfterClass method:

```
def cleanupSpec() {
    RULE.testSupport.after()
}
```

Or just use @Rule instead of @ClassRule and call

```
def setup() {
    RULE.application.run()
}
```

inside of @Before method instead of @BeforeClass.
Though It seems strange, maybe there is some other better solution exists..

Answer (score 0):

public class TestMain extends Main{

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
    new TestMain().run(args);
}


@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<AppConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    super.initialize(bootstrap);
    bootstrap.addBundle(
                    new MigrationsBundle<AppConfiguration>() {
                        @Override
                        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(
                                        AppConfiguration configuration) {
                            return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
                        }
                    });
}
```

}

Comment: simply extend the main class then add testing-specific stuff there should work, I init h2 in-mem DB just for testing this way